# Filter an Array containing Integers and Strings

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am trying to make a method to filter an Array containing positive Integers and Strings leaving only Integers but weirdly my code doesn't work.

```
def filter_list(l)
 l.map { |items| items.is_a?(Integer) ? items : l.delete(items) }
end

filter_list([1,2,'a','b'])
```

In theory, my code works, because if I replace `items` and `l.delete(items)` with words as 'true' and 'false' Integer and Strings are being replaced correctly returning

```
[true, true, false, false]
```

But, keeping `items : l.delete(items)` it return me

```
[1, 2, "a"] or sometimes [1, 2, "b"]
```

So just one is deleted. How can I alter my method to return only integers?

Comment: In order to safely modify a collection while iterating over it, you have to know and understand the exact mechanics. To simplify this, Ruby provides – among others – [`Array#delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) and [`Array#keep_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-keep_if), so you don't have to bother.

Answer (score 5):

Your code doesn't work because you delete elements from the array with `l.delete` while you iterate over the same array.

Imagine you walk an array with 4 elements and at the same time, someone changes the number of elements in the array and their positions.

I think you are looking for [`Array#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
array = [1, 2, 'a', 'b']
array.select { |element| element.is_a?(Integer) }
#=> [1, 2]
```

Comment: Ok thanks, this could be another way but why mine doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are altering the array your are `map`ping if your item is not an integer.

When your `map` first visits the element `'a'` it calls `l.delete('a')` (which return `'a'`). This means that `'l'` no longer is your initial array that your `map` over. Instead of the initial `[1, 2, 'a', 'b']` your array `l` now contains `[1, 2, 'b']`.

I am not sure about the exact implementation of `map` but I guess that now the array was altered and contains just three instead of four elements, `map` does not look at the final `'b'` in your array.
Let's assume you have an array `a = [1, 2, 'a', 'b']`.

The first time you call `filter_list(a)` it returns `[1, 2, 'a']`. If you now print `a` you will get the contents of your altered array: `[1, 2, 'b']`. Why is this different than the result of your function call? Because map creates a new array containing the return values of your `map` (and `delete` returns the deleted value, which in the first call results in `'a'`). But as `'a'` was deleted from our array `a` the result of our array is `[1, 2, 'b']`.

The next time you call `filter_list(a)` it `map`s over `[1, 2, 'b']`. This results in a second call to `delete` which returns `'b'`. Thus `map` returns a new array containing `[1, 2, 'b']`. After this second call to `filter_list` you have altered your input array again so that our array `a` now contains only `[1, 2]`.

If you call `filter_list(a)` again, you will get `[1, 2]` as a result and `a` will not be altered again as there are no string left in the array to be removed.

You should always be careful about altering your input data as it might have (and in this case has) unintended side effects.

A better alternative to your implementation is using Ruby's `select` method (which is a filter method)(https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
a = [1, 2, 'a', 'b']

a.select { |element| element.is_a?(Integer) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3.4, 'a', 'b', [:c], { d: 1 }]

a.grep Integer  #=> [1, 2]
a.grep Float    #=> [3.4]
a.grep Numeric  #=> [1, 2, 3.4]
a.grep String   #=> ['a', 'b']
a.grep Array    #=> [[:c]]
a.grep Hash     #=> [{ :d => 1 }]
```

See [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep).

Answer (score 0):

`.delete(items)` returns `items` which is mapped into array.

in your console,

```
arr = [1,2,'a','b']
arr.delete('b')
# => 'b'
arr
# => [1, 2, 'a']
```

Thus, delete works too, but it returns deleted element and so can't be mapped because `.map` creates an array of whatever value the block returns.

If you want to use `.delete` then,

```
def filter_list(l)
  l.dup.each{ |e| l.delete(e) unless e.is_a?(Integer) }
  l
end
```

which is inefficient so, try

```
l.select { |items| items.is_a?(Integer) }
```

Comment: What do you mean with:                                                                  .delete(items) returns items which is mapped into array?  Why .delete doesn't works properly? Thanks

Comment: see updated answer, `.map` does is create an array of whatever the `block` returns.

Comment: Oook! Maybe I have understood. Correct me if wrong:  Reading Ruby Doc it says that .delete  RETURN the items that it delete and in the same time, in my code, .map! is mapping the array keeping what is returned by the block. Right? This is why 'a' despite is deleted is kept in the array. Right?.  And why b is not returned as well? maybe because is the last item and map doesn't 'mapping' anymore?  What a mess :P. If is correct what i said now i can use .select

Comment: exactly, and also a point to note that you were modifying the same array you were mapping on to. As you can see I have used `.dup` which creates duplicate of original array and performs operation.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is the correct answer if you want instances of one specific class.

If you want to group elements by classes, you could write:

```
strings, integers = [1,2,'a','b'].group_by(&:class).values_at(String, Fixnum)
strings
# => ["a", "b"]
integers
# => [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use the code you wrote, you could do something like that:

```
def filter_list(l)
  i = l.length
  while i > 0 
    l.map { |items| items.is_a?(Integer) ? items : l.delete(items) }
    i -= 1
  end
  l
end

filter_list([1, 2, 'a', 'b', 3, 'duh', 'isitover?']) # will return [1, 2, 3]
```